# Net Socket Connections in OpenShift

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a net socket Nodejs server for my embedded device to send data to on OpenShift.

I am trying to create this simple echo service

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
var PORT = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT  || 3000;

console.log('IP:' + HOST + ' Port:' + PORT);

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
console.log('client connected');

connection.on('end', function() {console.log('client disconnected');});

connection.write('Hello World!\r\n');
connection.pipe(connection);
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST , function() {
console.log('server is listening');
});
```

I according to OpenShift's Port Binding [Guide](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html) I had my client application connect to Port 8000.

For Testing I am using the following code from my desktop machine.

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = 'nodejs-myapplication.rhcloud.com';
var PORT = 8000;

var client = net.connect(PORT, HOST,  function() {
console.log('connected to server!');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
console.log(data.toString());
client.end();
});
client.on('end', function() {
console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

The Client Scripts gets to Connected to server and gets stuck there itself. Nothing takes place after that.

Now if I open the address nodejs-myapplication.rhcloud.com:8000 in my browser, the NodeJS Server logs a client connected and disconnected, but when the NodeClient is connected the server doesn't show any update. The Node Client just says connected and stays there without doing anything.

If I run the same scripts locally it works fine, ( Locally i use HOst as 127.0.0.1 and port as 3000).

How can I get a TCP Application to connect to the Openshift NodeJS Server?

The Device will be sending ASCII output over the socket eg. $VAR,12,23,21\r\n

I need to be able to read that data, convert it to JSON and send it out to another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be loaded on a platform like DigitalOcean with a firewall enabled.
OpenShift doesn't allow custom ports by default so need a workaround for that.